# Inheriting attributes from prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am working on a school assignment and I want to inherit the properties of a previous constructor function. I used object.create but when I make a new object that inherits the previous properties it doesn't assign the properties correctly.

I tried to change the syntax of how I wrote the new object and I tried reviewing the notes from my school.

```
            function GameObject(createdAt,name,dimensions){
              this.createdAt = createdAt;
              this.name = name;
              this.dimensions = dimensions;
            }
            GameObject.prototype.destroy = function(){
              return `${this.name} was removed from the game.`
            }
            const hi = new GameObject(
            "microsoft","hi","300 X 600")
            console.log(hi)
            console.log(hi.destroy())
            /*
              === CharacterStats ===
              * healthPoints
              * takeDamage() // prototype method -> returns the string '<object name> took damage.'
              * should inherit destroy() from GameObject's prototype
            */
            function CharacterStats(healthPoints){
              this.healthPoints = healthPoints
              GameObject.call(this, healthPoints)

            }
            CharacterStats.prototype.takeDamage = function(){
              return this.name + " took damage."
            }
            CharacterStats.prototype = Object.create(GameObject.prototype)
            const yay = new CharacterStats(
              "microsoft","hi","300 X 600")
            console.log(yay)
```

I want the yay object to inherit not only the healthPoints property correctly but also the properties from GameObject

Comment: What should `healthPoints` be? You are only passing `"microsoft","hi","300 X 600"` to the function?

Answer (score 0):

The attributes are not created by anything related to the prototype, they are created by your call to the `GameObject` constructor. But you are not passing the right arguments there, it should be

```
function CharacterStats(createdAt, name, dimensions, healthPoints) {
//                      ^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^
  GameObject.call(this, createdAt, name, dimensions);
//                      ^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^
  this.healthPoints = healthPoints;
}
```

Then you can do

```
const yay = new CharacterStats("stackoverflow", "marcus", "300 X 600", 8);
```